# Convert deep nested array in javascript to CSV

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, tree, export-to-csv

I have a deep nested array that needs to converted into a downloadable CSV. I am trying to build the CSV file by iterating through each array and subarray. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

This is what the nested array looks like:

```
[{
    id: 123,
    name: "ABC",
    superDepartment: [{
        id: 456,
        name: "PQR",
        keyCompetitor: ["JKL"],
        department: [{
            id: 765,
            name: "XYZ",
            category: [{
                id: 965,
                name: "GHJ",
                keyCompetitor: ["NMK"],
                otherCompetitor: ["SDF", "LKJ"],
                subcategory: [
                    {id: 346, name: "DRJ"},
                    {id: 789, name: "SRE"}        
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];
```

Expected output in CSV

| SBU | Super Department | Department | Category | Subcategory | Key Competitor | Core Competitor | Other Competitor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | PQR |  |  |  | JKL |  |  |
|  |  | XYZ |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | GHJ |  | NMK |  | SDF, LKJ |
|  |  |  |  | DRJ |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | SRE |  |  |  |

This is what I have so far:

```
let csvData = [];
downloadData.map(data => {
    if(csvData.length === 0) {
        csvData.push(data.name, "", "", "", csvData.keyCompetitors ? csvData.keyCompetitors[0] : "",
        csvData.coreCompetitors ?  csvData.coreCompetitors.join(): "",
        csvData.otherCompetitors ? csvData.otherCompetitors.join() : "")
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do the strings "SBU" and "Core Competitor" come from, since they are not present in the input? How is the order of the output columns defined by the input, since there the order of first occurrence is different?

Comment: Please edit your question to properly format the nested array. JS array in no way looks like the one you shared

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in several phases:

- Get the rows from the nested structure, where each row is an object with the properties that were specified for that row. Assume that the toplevel values belong to the "SBU" property. This function could use recursion to deal with the nesting, and it could be a *generator* function.
- Get the list of distinct properties that are used throughout the data from the previous step, in an order that gives priority to properties that had nested content.
- Use the previous information to complete the objects from step 1 with missing properties, so all objects have the same properties in the same order
- Turn that result into a matrix that has the property names as header row, but with camelCase turned into separate words.
- Turn that result into a CSV string, using quotes to wrap values that could otherwise lead to ambiguity, escaping (doubling) double quotes that are in the data. You could use a library for that, but here I have defined a function for it.

Implementation:

```js
// Function to determine whether the argument is an object array or not
const isObjectArray = arr => Array.isArray(arr) && Object(arr[0]) === arr[0];

// Generator function to list the rows encoded by a nested object structure
function* getRows(data, field="SBU") {
    for (const {id, name, ...obj} of data) {
        const categories = [[[field, name]], []];
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            categories[+isObjectArray(value)].push([key, value]);
        }
        yield Object.fromEntries(categories[0]);
        for (const [key, value] of categories[1]) {
            yield* getRows(value, key);
        }
    }
}

// Function to convert camelCase to separate words in title case
const wordify = camelCase =>
    camelCase.replace(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g, " $&").trim()
             .replace(/^[a-z]/, a => a.toUpperCase());

// Function to get the list of properties used by objects in an array
const getColumns = rows => [...
    new Set([
        ...rows.map(row => Object.keys(row)[0]), // Priority columns
        ...rows.flatMap(Object.keys) // Other columns
    ])
];

// Function to complete objects in an array with missing properties
const completeObjects = rows => {
    const template = Object.fromEntries(getColumns(rows).map(column => [column, ""]));
    return rows.map(row => Object.assign({}, template, row));
};

// Function to turn an object array into a matrix of strings, including a header row
const toMatrix = fullRows => [
    Object.keys(fullRows[0]).map(wordify), // Header
    ...fullRows.map(row => Object.values(row).map(String)) // Data
];

// Function to prepare a string to be included as a CSV value
const csvEscape = s =>
    !s.match(/[\n\r," ]/) ? s
    : '"' + s.replaceAll('"', '""') + '"';

// Function to turn a matrix into CSV formatted string
const toCsv = matrix =>
    matrix.map(row => row.map(csvEscape).join(",")).join("\n");

// Example input:
const downloadData = [{
    id: 123,
    name: "ABC",
    superDepartment: [{
        id: 456,
        name: "PQR",
        keyCompetitor: ["JKL"],
        department: [{
            id: 765,
            name: "XYZ",
            category: [{
                id: 965,
                name: "GHJ",
                keyCompetitor: ["NMK"],
                otherCompetitor: ["SDF", "LKJ"],
                subcategory: [
                    {id: 346, name: "DRJ"},
                    {id: 789, name: "SRE"}        
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];

const csv = toCsv(toMatrix(completeObjects([...getRows(downloadData)])));
console.log(csv);
```

Note that there is no "Core Competitor" column in the output, since this appears nowhere in the sample input.